# How to deploy and use custom python package on azure as a service and consume it

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I have created a custom python package which has few machine learning algorithms in it.

I would like to deploy this custom python package on azure as a service that can be consume by my other applications like a batch job and a website.

I have bought an azure license but have no clue on the deployment strategy. Please advice

Comment: Not sure what's your target. What azure license you bought? Do you want to deploy python package on azure web service so that it can be called by other services?

Comment: I have a pay as you go license. Yes i want to deploy my python package and run it in a job. This job will retrieve and store data in azure storage

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the following **[documentation](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/vstsextend/python/)**, it will allow you to Deploy Python application to Azure App Service using VSTS.The lab would provide you with the same skills to deploy your app to Azure App service.